# Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' whereas both the arg passes are lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to code for a problem definition which is : 
Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

My code is:

```
def summer_69(arr):     
    mylist=[]     
    for i,x in enumerate(arr):         
        if x==9:             
           end=i             
           break         
        elif x==6:             
           start=i             
           continue     
        mylist.append(arr[start:end+1:])     
     return (sum(arr)-sum(mylist))
```

What's wrong I'm doing with the above code?

Comment: What is `end` after the first iteration of the `for`? Looks like if `x != 9` then it will be undefined.

Comment: I've used end variable to store the value when the char finds a 9 in an array
I may be wrong since I'm new to programming

Comment: Dedent `mylist.append(arr[start:end+1:]) `

Comment: Right, but lets say the loop executes the first time, what if `x != 9`. You havent defined what `end` is when that is the case.

Comment: @Chirag, if i/p is [1, 4, 7, 8, 6, 9, 8, 6 ,9, 9, 9, 5, 6, 9, 5] then what o/p you expect?

Comment: The i/p provided won't have more than one 69 pairs.Some text o/p
summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14

Comment: Okay **@Chirag**. Thanks for your comment. I will modify my code. I misunderstood and answerd according to that.

Comment: **@Chirag**, I have updated the code. Please check it. It works fine for the set of inputs that you provided in comment. Please test it with multiple inputs that you have in your mind which has the great chance to fail the code and let me know if it fails. Thanks very much for your help (as you provided inputs).

Comment: **@Chirag**, I checked your code and updated it in my answer. It works fine for all inputs that you have provided in comment. As I am not sure about o/p for i/p `[12, 34, 6, 9, 9, 9, 4]`, the updated code based on your logic will return `12+34+9+9+4` = 68 and I'm sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**@Chirag**, as I well understood from your comment and provided inputs  & expected outputs.

I found, your code has variables named **start** and **end** defined inside if-else block which causes error **UnboundLocalError**  if the first item of list neither 6 nor 9.

As well as you don't need to use any extra list **mylist** as we already have **start** and **end** variables to keep track of the position of 6 and 9.

> **Input** => **Output**
>
> [1, 3, 5] => 9
>
> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] => 9
>
> [2, 1, 6, 9, 11] => 14

Have a look at your updated code which works fine for the set of inputs that you have provided in comment.

```
def summer_69(arr):     
    start, end = -1, -1
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):         
        if x==9:             
           end = i             
           break         
        elif x==6:             
           start = i             
    return (sum(arr) - sum(arr[start:end+1]))
```

I've also written the following working code which works for the set of inputs that you've provided in comment.

> Please check it with your set of inputs and let me know if it fails. I will modify the code to make it working.

```
def summer_69(arr):     
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr) :         
        if arr[i] == 6:             
            start = i
            i = i + 1
            while(i < len(arr) and arr[i] != 9):
                i = i + 1;
            arr = arr[0: start] + arr[i+1:]
        else:
            i = i + 1;

    return sum(arr);

array = [1, 3, 5]
array2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array3 = [2, 1, 6, 9, 11]

array_sum = summer_69(array);
print(array, "=>", array_sum);

array_sum = summer_69(array2);
print(array2, "=>", array_sum);

array_sum = summer_69(array3);
print(array3, "=>", array_sum);

"""
[1, 3, 5] => 9
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] => 9
[2, 1, 6, 9, 11] => 14
"""
```

Comment: No problem, i think the code works fine. Enjoy programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `mylist` is a list of lists (since you're appending a slice of `arr` to it at the end of most iterations of the loop). When you `sum` the list, you're trying to add the values from `mylist` to an initial value for the sum, which by default is zero. You could delay the error by one operation by using `sum(mylist, [])` (adding to an empty list), but I suspect that you don't want `mylist` to be a list of lists at all.

To do what your code is attempting, I think you can skip the `start` and `end` bits and just do:

```
mylist.append(x)
```

This won't exactly work if you have multiple six-nine pairs in your input list (since you `break` out of the loop whenever you see a `9`), and it might not be computing the right value if the sixes and nines are supposed to be skipped as well as the numbers between them, but it should be a start.

Another approach might be to make a slice from a start index to an end index, but only when you are at the 9 in the iteration (not every cycle). That would look something like:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    mylist = []
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):         
        if x == 6:
           start = i
        elif x == 9:
           mylist.append(sum(arr[start:i+1]))
     return sum(arr) - sum(mylist)
```

In this version of the code, `mylist` contains the sums of the slices that should be excluded from the overall sum. I swapped the order of `if` and `elif` because it makes much more sense when you read it in this order (the code would still run the same if we kept the old order). There's no `else` block because we don't need to do anything special for non six or nine values.